# Using CMD+h/j/k/l as arrows in macOS

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Is it possible to set up cmd with h, j, k, l as in Vim (but using with cmd) as arrow keys for cursor movement?

Comment: unfortunately current time of writing there is no way to do it other than third party plugins. I don't know any plugin which can provide this function.

Comment: Karabinier can do this. The installable options include several mappings to do this.

Answer (score 7):

With [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), you can import a `complex_modifications rule` named [Left ctrl + hjkl to Arrow Keys Vim](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#ctrl_plus_hjkl_to_arrow_keys), it enables that:

> Left ctrl + hjkl to arrow keys Vim

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd> may not be a good idea, because almost all of the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-***** are used by the system and apps, e.g. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> is a system shortcut to hide the current app, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> would be better. However, if you don't need the system/app shortcuts, you can [custom the rule like this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/445689/35986).